# Passing password input to a salted hash token before insert to mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I am posting data from a form to this logic to register users. The question i have is how do i take the information posted to the $userpw variable in this logic and pass it to the token and then insert the token contents into the db as the users password. I am very new to PHP, please go easy on me. do i litterally just change the insert statement to include the token variable instead of the userpw one?

```
//---sanitize function on a different file.
require 'sanitize.php';

//-------------variables including the hashed token--------------
  $userid   = $username= $userpw = $userfname = $userlname = '';
  $salt     = "qm&h*";
  $pepper   = "pg!@";
  $token    = hash('ripemd128', "$salt$userpw$pepper");


//--------existing insert logic-------------
if (isset($_POST['user_name'])    &&
    isset($_POST['user_pw']) &&
    isset($_POST['user_fname']) &&
    isset($_POST['user_lname']))
  {

    $username      = sanitizeString($_POST['user_name']);
    $userpw        = sanitizeString($_POST['user_pw']);
    $userfname     = sanitizeString($_POST['user_fname']);
    $userlname     = sanitizeString($_POST['user_lname']);
    $query    = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_pw, user_fname, user_lname) VALUES" .
      "('$username', '$userpw', '$userfname', '$userlname')";
         $result   = $conn->query($query);

    if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
      $conn->error . "<br><br>";
```

Comment: Use `password_hash()` when storing the password, and `password_verify()` when checking the password.

Comment: ^...and do not concatenate data to a query, use prepared statements instead

Comment: The salt should be unique per password, but just use `password_hash()` and let it generate a salt for you.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: this is for a learning project, not production. I understand that there are better ways to do it, but i want to understand the logic doing it this way.

Comment: If you want to learn the wrong way to do it, this is the way to go. If you want to learn the *right* way you're going to need to check that A) You're using prepared statements with placeholder values. B) You're using a password-grade hashing function like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) which [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) conveniently uses by default, and C) That you've got good examples to work from, not YouTube tutorials written by people with no idea what they're doing.

Comment: This stuff is very hard to get perfectly right, and anything less than perfect exposes you, your users, and probably your company to enormous risks. For example, a single SQL injection hole is all that's needed to cause total chaos and destroy or compromise the production database.

Comment: @tadman I completely agree, I am just following the learning process outlined in a book and trying to adapt the methods given to a internal test site with no commercial application or user exposure. Purely educational.

Comment: Which book is this? It looks like it was written in the 1990s and never updated if this is what they recommend you do. This sort of code was highly suspect back then, password crackers were getting much better, and it's downright hazardous today with high-speed parallel GPU cracking being common-place.

Comment: It's "Learning PHP, MySQL, & JavaScript" by Robin Nixon. It's just a beginner's guide that is explaining the basic concept of password hashing. It's not suggesting that i apply this technique in real world production.

Comment: IMO if a book or a tutorial recommends such things, you abandon it and look for a better one. If you are learning, learn good practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, this is the correct change:

```
if (isset($_POST['user_name'])    &&
    isset($_POST['user_pw']) &&
    isset($_POST['user_fname']) &&
    isset($_POST['user_lname']))
  {

    $username      = sanitizeString($_POST['user_name']);
    $userpw        = sanitizeString($_POST['user_pw']);
    $userfname     = sanitizeString($_POST['user_fname']);
    $userlname     = sanitizeString($_POST['user_lname']);
    $query    = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_pw, user_fname, user_lname) VALUES" .
      "('$username', '$token', '$userfname', '$userlname')";
         $result   = $conn->query($query);
```